# DUPLICATES IN LEFT JOIN MYSQL QUERY

Tags: mysql

please help, how can i remove duplicates

whenever i have more than two rows on each table they duplicate

The (getter_tbl) result keeps on duplicating on whenever the (helper) table rows increases

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.status as h_status, h.ph_amount as h_ph_amount, h.help_id as h_help_id, h.h_unique_id as h_h_unique_id, h.user_id as h_user_id, h.ph_date as h_ph_date, h.ph_commitment as h_ph_commitment, h.ph_type as h_ph_type,
g.status as g_status, g.user_id as g_user_id, g.getter_tbl_id as g_getter_tbl_id, g.gh_committment as g_gh_committment, g.gh_type as g_gh_type, g.status as g_status, g.method as g_method, g.amount as g_amount,
u.nickname as u_nickname, u.user_id as u_user_id
FROM helper AS h
LEFT JOIN getter_tbl AS g ON h.user_id = g.user_id
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = '{$user_id}'
WHERE h.user_id = '{$user_id}' AND g.user_id='{$user_id}' AND h.status='open' OR g.status='open'
GROUP BY h.help_id, g.getter_tbl_id, u.user_id
```

this my code

```
foreach($query as $queryRows){
    if($queryRows['g_status'] == 'open'){
      print '
        <div class="block-content block-content-full text-left text-black" style="padding: 10px 15px 1px; ">
        <div class="font-size-sm text-black-op" style=" color: black !important; "><strong>Amount:</strong> '.number_format($queryRows['g_gh_committment'], 0).'</div>
        <div class="font-size-sm text-black-op" style=" color: black !important; "><strong>Balance:</strong> '.number_format($queryRows['g_gh_committment'], 0).'</div>

      ';
    }
    if($queryRows['h_status'] == 'open'){
      print '
        <div class="block-content block-content-full text-left text-black" style="padding: 10px 15px 1px; ">
        <div class="font-size-sm text-black-op" style=" color: black !important; "><strong>Amount:</strong> '.number_format($queryRows['h_ph_amount'], 0).'</div>
        <div class="font-size-sm text-black-op" style=" color: black !important; "><strong>Balance:</strong> '.number_format($queryRows['h_ph_commitment'], 0).'</div>

      ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @mech i have tried INNER JOIN am still having same results

Answer (score 0):

It was getting really hard to be clear in a comment -- so I'm offering a *potential* answer.

You duplicate your `user_id` several times. Perhaps that is the reason you are duplicating your results.

Also your SQL syntax likely has a bug. I'm assuming your WHERE clause should be AND (h.status=open OR g.status=open). In that, you want to get the user when either of those status are open.

Does this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

h.status as h_status, 
h.ph_amount as h_ph_amount, 
h.help_id as h_help_id, 
h.h_unique_id as h_h_unique_id, 
h.ph_date as h_ph_date, 
h.ph_commitment as h_ph_commitment, 
h.ph_type as h_ph_type,
g.status as g_status, 
g.getter_tbl_id as g_getter_tbl_id, 
g.gh_committment as g_gh_committment, 
g.gh_type as g_gh_type, 
g.status as g_status, 
g.method as g_method, 
g.amount as g_amount,
u.nickname as u_nickname,
u.user_id as u_user_id

FROM helper AS h
LEFT JOIN getter_tbl AS g ON h.user_id = g.user_id
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = h.user_id

WHERE 
u.user_id = '{$user_id}' AND 
(h.status='open' OR g.status='open')

GROUP BY h.help_id, g.getter_tbl_id, u.user_id
```

**NOTE**: It will only return u_user_id (and not the same id in 3 different variables)